# cannot get the list view id

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-count-theme="c" data-inset="true">
            <li class="custom-li">
                <div  id="xn"  data-role="collapsible" class="custom-collapsible" >
                    <h4>Heading</h4>
                    <ul id="tweet-list1" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c"  class="collapsible_list">
                        <li data-role="list-divider">
                            <h2 style="text-align:center;" data-theme="c">Items</h2>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>

 $('.custom-collapsible').bind('expand', function() {
                alert($(this, "ul").attr('id'));
            });
```

I need to get the id of the list view when i the collpsable panel expand.But when i try above code i get the collpsable panel id instead of list view id

Comment: `$('.custom-collapsible').bind('expand', function () {
    alert($("ul", this).attr('id'));
});` `this` should come after `ul`. Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bRK2Q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 alert($(this).find('.collapsible_list').attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
alert($(this).find("ul").attr('id'));
```

**fiddle**  http://jsfiddle.net/bmAjg/